# bytes captured limited at 15 bytes on wireshark for BLE

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, wireshark, android-bluetooth

[image]

I'm recovering BLE logs from my phone after enabling HCI logging and following [this](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/bluetooth/verifying_debugging#debugging-with-bug-reports)
The problem is as showed in the figure, it seems that the number of bytes captured is limited at 15 bytes. Notice the 32 bytes on wire, 15 bytes captured, this is like this for all packets > 15 bytes.

How can I explore the packets at full length?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding what I missed before, so I'll write it here in case someone faces the same issue.

The problem comes from not finding the *.log file in the same location as found in other guides and I ended up using the bugreport*.txt file with btsnooz.py to generate the log file.

But in my case the file extension was `.cfa.curf` and the file could be found in `FS/data/misc/bluetooth/logs/BT_HCI_2023_0604_000829.cfa.curf` and using that one, captured bytes == bytes on wire